# Magento 2 : Can We Add Data From Custom Module to Core Database?

Tags: magento2, php, database, customer

If I want to insert form data in to the "customer_entity" table How can we achieve that?

I have mentioned all fields in the form as "create an account", and rather than creating a new table in the database I want to insert the data in the Magento's core customer table.

Thanks for help in advance !!

Comment: Can you describe your requirement in detail what you are looking for?

Comment: I have created a form in the custom module with the same fields as create account form has, the issue is I want to add data of custome module form data in the table where "create account" form data is getting stored (the dB table remain the same for custom form and create and account form)! that's how I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following things.

1. When that data post, you need to create customer programmatically so you do not want to make the entry manually on the relevant table.

To create customer programmatically, you can read this article : https://magecomp.com/blog/create-customer-programmatically-magento-2/

Comment: this is without creating the new form new customer data can be added! right?

Comment: Yes, you can take the data from your form and pass the respective data on your code and you will able to do that one.

Comment: ok ! got it, I'll try this way, thanks!!

Comment: If Answer help then upvote and mark as solution so it will help other in community.